# Javascription Function Variables with a common ID

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a PHP page with form elements with trailing common ID. Eg:

```
Dropdown - dd1039
Div - div1039 
Price Div - pd1039
```

And I want to set the onChange of the dropdown to call myFunction(1039) instead writing each element id is this possible?

So rather doing this:

```
function myFunction(dropdownelement, divelement, pdelement) {
.
.
.
.
}

myFunction(dd1039, div1039, pd1039)
```

Is it possible to do this instead:

```
function myFunction(itemID) {
     "dd"+ itemID.value.... 
     .
     .
     .
}

myFunction(1039)
```

Comment: what you want ??

Comment: The ID of an element should be UNIQUE. If you need a common ID, use a CLASS name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `document.querySelectorAll('[id^="dd"]')` to get every id that starts with what you want, then get the number from the id attribute, and add the event listener to call the function.

```
function myFunction(id)  {
    const dropdown = document.getElementById(`dd${id}`);
    const div = document.getElementById(`div${id}`);
    const priceDiv = document.getElementById(`pd${id}`);
    // do stuff
}

// get any element with an id starting with dd
const dropDowns = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="dd"]');

for (var i = 0; i < dropDowns.length; i++) {
    const dropDown = dropDowns[i];
    // get everything after dd
    const generalID = dropDown.id.substring(2);
    // just in case
    if (!Number.isInterger(Number(generalID)) {
        continue;
    }
    dropdown.addEventListener('change', myFunction.bind(generalID));
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a global (`document`) event listener then you should add the listener to the `document` and validate the `target` within the event.

```js
const handleDropDownChange = dropdown => {
  const
    { id, value } = dropdown,
    [match, idAsString] = id.match(/^dd(\d+)$/),
    idAsNumber = parseInt(idAsString, 10);

  console.log(`Changed ${idAsNumber} to ${value}`);
}

const handleGlobalDropDownChange = ({ target: el }) => {
  if (el.classList.contains('dropdown')) {
    handleDropDownChange(el);
  }
};

document.addEventListener('change', handleGlobalDropDownChange);
```

```html
<select id="dd1039" class="dropdown">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<select id="dd1042" class="dropdown">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Polywhirl! Thisone isa bit more advance for my noob brain. I think I can use this too. Will test it out. Thank you!